# about ruby class method invoke

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

in rails3 i defined a class

```
#coding:utf-8
class CoreMail < ActionMailer::Base
  def consulting_reply(email)
    mail(:to => email, :subject => 'ssss')

  end



end
```

i found i could invoke this method like this

```
CoreMail.consulting_reply(email)
```

but want i thought the right way is :

```
instance=CoreMail.new
instance.consulting_reply(email)
```

because the consulting_reply is the instance method,

did i missing something? hope someone could give me a help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, normally that would be an instance method and you would have to create an instance of the class before calling consulting_reply() (since it's not defined as self.consulting_reply).  However, your class is inheriting from ActionMailer::Base, and there's a little ruby magic happening behind the scenes. Checkout the source for ActionMailer::Base to see it for yourself (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb), but to simplify for you what's happening, here's a quick example:

```
class Test
  def self.method_missing(method, *args)
    puts "Called by a non class method"
  end
end

Test.fake_class_method
```

Which will output:

Called by a non class method

ActionMailer::Base does something similar to this, which dynamically looks for the method you called. I believe it also creates a instance of the class using:

```
new(method, *args).message
```

Anyway, I hope this sheds some light as to what's happening.

Comment: Isn't this what I posted, only longer? Sorry to be a spoil sport :(

Comment: I was writing it the same time you were writing your answer :P

Answer (score 2):

`ActionMailer::Base` has a `method_missing` defined on it:

```
def method_missing(method, *args) #:nodoc:
  return super unless respond_to?(method)
  new(method, *args).message
end
```

This will call your instance method with the same arguments and then call the `message` method, returning the object of that mailer call. To deliver it, call `deliver!` on the end of your method call:

```
CoreMail.consulting_reply(email).deliver!
```